# New NVIDIA drivers blacks out one of dual monitor setup

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a NVIDIA GTX 590 running version 365.19 drivers. I have a BenQ XL2420Z and a Spectre monitor. Whenever I update my drivers to anything after 365.19, my BenQ monitor goes into some sort of "standby" mode. It's backlit but there's no video output. Even if I restart the computer it's still backlit with no video output. My other monitor works fine. Also, my computer still functions like it's using both monitors, where I can move my mouse on both monitors (but I obviously can't see it on my BenQ monitor). They're both hooked up to the 590's DVI connectors.

Comment: I've had this happen a few times. Quick workaround is to unplug or switch off one monitor, update, and plug it back in. At some point I had both monitors work automatically so I don't know what changed

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I tried that, it still didn't work, but I did switch the cables (the Scepter had an HDMI while the BenQ had a DVI). That worked until I restarted my computer and the BenQ blacked out again.

Comment: It seems only one of them works on startup, but if I disconnect and reconnect both of the monitors they both work, but only until the next startup.

Comment: Try 376.33 driver version.